# How to sort the results of Counter.mostCommon(n) lexicographically (by counter, then by value)?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

How can I sort the results of `Counter.mostCommon` by the counter, and then the value?

My original code:

```
from collections import Counter
for counter in Counter("abcdefg").most_common(3): 
    print(counter[0], counter[1])
```

The output is different every time, since each value has a count of 1.
Sometimes it is

```
a 1
b 1
e 1
```

sometimes

```
b 1
d 1
f 1
```

etc.

**I want this:**

```
a 1
b 1
c 1
```

I've also tried sorting the resulting tuples::

```
from collections import Counter
for counter in sorted(Counter("abcdefg").most_common(3), key=lambda x: x[0]): print(counter[0], counter[1])
```

and sorting the string

```
from collections import Counter
for counter in Counter(sorted("abcdefg")).most_common(3): print(counter[0], counter[1])
```

but I get the same unpredictable results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that `Counter` dicts are unordered, and `most_common` doesn't care about the keys.  To accomplish this, you need to sort the dict's items and then pull off the 3 most common.

```
counter = Counter('abcdef')
most_common = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda pair: (-pair[1], pair[0]))
```

This will sort on `-pair[1]` (the counts) first.  Higher counts will appear first because of the negative.  Next we sort on `pair[0]` (the key) which will order lexicographically in normal increasing order.

From here, you need to slice off the items that you want ...

```
most_common[:3]
```

---

Alternatively, we can take a page out of [the source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l472) and re-implement `most_common` to take the keys into account.

```
import heapq as _heapq

def most_common(counter, n=None):
    '''List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
    common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.

    >>> Counter('abcdeabcdabcaba').most_common(3)
    [('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)]

    '''
    # Emulate Bag.sortedByCount from Smalltalk
    sort_key = lambda pair: (-pair[1], pair[0])
    if n is None:
        return sorted(counter.iteritems(), key=sort_key)
    return _heapq.nsmallest(n, counter.iteritems(), key=sort_key)
```

Comment: I get different ordered results on each execution.

Comment: @JamesWierzba -- Yeah, sorry about that.  Updated my solution.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I edited your answer changing `iteritems` to `items` because I'm on python 3.4.3. Thanks for your help.